# Problems setting up a simple RMI server

Tags: java, rmi

I am having a problem setting up a simple RMI server, and was wondering if someone can point me in the right direction.

I have a simple class, Server, that should export an simple interface.  Currently when I try and run the server class, I get the following exception:

```
java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: prototype.ISimpleService
```

I have already made sure that the rmi registry is running, by running the "start rmiregistry" command, and I am running the service with the following argument

```
-Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:C:/Users/John/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Prototype/build/classes
```

The path in the argument above points to the top level folder of my class hierarchy, so:

/classes

/prototype

->ISimpleService.class

->SimpleServiceImpl.class

->IServer.class

Here is my server code:

```
public class Server
{
    private static ISimpleService service;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        service = new SimpleServiceImpl();

        try
        {
            ISimpleService stub = (ISimpleService) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(service, 0);

            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();

            registry.rebind("SimpleService", stub);

            System.out.println("Simple Service bound");
        } 
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception binding the simple service");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I have looked at the Java RMI trail, and adapted my simple example to follow that, although I am not using security/permissions that I shouldn't need as I have gotten an RMI example working before without that stuff...

So I believe I have to missing something simple(no pun intended), to make this work, but I cant see anything at the moment.

Do anyone have an ideas?

Here is the full stack trace:

```
java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: prototype.ISimpleService
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:396)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:250)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask    (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer    (StreamRemoteCall.java:255)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:233)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:359)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.rebind(Unknown Source)
    at prototype.Server.main(Server.java:35)
Caused by: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: prototype.ISimpleService
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Skel.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:386)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:250)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask    (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: prototype.ISimpleService
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadProxyInterfaces(LoaderHandler.java:711)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadProxyClass(LoaderHandler.java:655)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadProxyClass(LoaderHandler.java:592)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadProxyClass(RMIClassLoader.java:628)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadProxyClass(RMIClassLoader.java:294)
    at sun.rmi.server.MarshalInputStream.resolveProxyClass(MarshalInputStream.java:238)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1530)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1492)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1731)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
    ... 12 more
```

Comment: Can you please post the exception full stack trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this issue...  Took me alittle longer than I expected though :(

Turns out when you use a codebase argument like I had done, you should place a trailing "/" at the end, if you are pointing to a directory.  Once I added that in, my server successfully binds.

For a resource on this p see http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/rmi/codebase.html#section6

Answer (score 0):

It seems `prototype.ISimpleService` is not in your classpath.

Try:

```
java -cp=C:/Users/John/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Prototype/build/classes;C:/Users/John/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Server/build/classes Server
```

Comment: That hasnt worked for me, also when I add in a few System.out.println statements, to narrow down which line causes the problem, this line is what throws up the problem:   "registry.rebind("SimpleService", stub);"  ISimpleService has already been used in the server class by this point, and it doesn't throw any issues for those lines....

Comment: @user270349 That's not correct. You are thinking of NoClassDefFoundError.

Comment: You are right @EJP, I will remove the comment, yours will be out of context, sorry.